# How do I apply a mask over my whole image?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am having a tough time getting a mask to cover over my whole image just using Bootstrap-5. How can I do that?

Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pjg9qkd1/) and my code below:

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-5 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Body -->
<div class="bg-image">
  <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/new/standard/city/053.jpg" class="w-100" />
  <div class="mask" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add the class `position-relative` to the parent element. 
Then `position-absolute`+ `top-0` + `end-0` + `bottom-0` + `start-0` to the overlay.

No z-index needed by default.

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-5 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Body -->
<div class="bg-image position-relative">
  <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/new/standard/city/053.jpg" class="w-100" />
  <div class="mask position-absolute top-0 end-0 bottom-0 start-0 " style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Inline styles should be avoided whenever possible. Even an embedded style tag is better.

Comment: I did not add the `inline-style` I just added the mentioned Bootstrap classes. But It also could be added by SASS if he want to go fully Bootstrap. Personally I would favor custom CSS to use `inset: 0` which would be so much shorter to code.

Comment: Fair enough, but it would be trivial to move the styling for `.mask` to a style tag.

Answer (score 3):

You could dump a bunch of [Bootstrap positioning classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/position/) in your markup, but since you'll need custom CSS anyway, I'd do it with that, either in an embedded tag or an external stylesheet. Inline styles should be strictly avoided. They're not easy to read or maintain.

The usual way is with a pseudo-element. This prevents the need for extra markup. Note that I'm using Bootstrap's `position-relative` class on the container rather than adding a custom style rule.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>     
  .bg-image:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  }
</style>

<div class="bg-image position-relative">
  <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/new/standard/city/053.jpg" class="w-100" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get an overlay you have to add this css code:

```
.bg-image{
   position: relative;
}

.mask{
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   left: 0px;
   top: 0px;
}
```

It's important to give `.bg-image` the position relative, because you want that the child element `.mask` behaves relative to it. Without it would overlay the whole `body`.